# run command line as administrator node JS

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line, node-modules, serverless

I am doing a `serverless` application. I need to deploy it. But I need to remove the sharp module from windows, and install Linux version, because it will deploy in Linux.
For mac you have this command

```js
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "rm -rf node_modules/sharp && npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 --target=8.10.0 sharp",
    "deploy": "serverless deploy -v",
    "postdeploy": "rm -rf node_modules/sharp && npm install sharp"
  }
```

I would like to know the command `npm install  --platform=linux --arch=x64 --target=8.10.0 sharp` as administrator windows

Comment: Did you give try with a docker container?

Comment: Why do you need to run this as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, fixed my problem, Please put as Answer question. If execute a command cmd as administrator